.NET 8 ISOLATED Azure Function - Binding attributes not working
I am porting an old .NET 6 in-process Azure Function app, to .NET 8 isolated worker model. I have an issue where it seems like the app configuration expression resolution for our Azure Function bindings no longer works in .NET 8 isolated.
For instance, this BlobTrigger function used to look like this with .NET 6 in-process:
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger(
    "%StorageContainer:SourceImages%/{name}")]
BlobClient blob)

We had an app setting for %StorageContainer:SourceImages% in local.settings.json:
...
"StorageContainer:SourceImages": "mycontainer",
....

The blob trigger would use the built in .NET expression resolution stuff, to grab the StorageContainer.SourceImages value, stick it in the trigger attribute, and everything worked great.
Now, in .NET 8 isolated worker, I have to change my function parameters / trigger information a bit.
[Function("PhotoDataIndexer")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger(
    "mycontainer/{name}",
    Connection = "BlobFuncConnectionString")]
string stream, string name)

This works, it's picking up the blobs.
However, I do not want to have to supply the container name mycontainer directly in the function definition. I want to keep using my app setting reference of %StorageContainer:SourceImages% to grab the name.
Is this not possible in .NET 8 isolated worker model?

yes, but it's not relevant to this thread. what i'm asking now has nothing to do with secrets, i just want to know if the expression resolution will work with .net 8 isolated, secrets or not.

No i mentioned it because it has been deleted,  as if it undeleted, it helps community

We want to use local.settings.json for developing, but also supply a settings.json file for production. The old way of adding a JSON file to the configuration builder does not work for binding expressions (but it still supplies the configuration value if used in a more traditional way--injecting configuration into a service). However, for trigger binding expressions, the %<key>% notation doesn't work unless the setting is set in Azure (manually or via a pipeline).

You  can use the same method in Isolated-process model.
This worked for me.
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace FunctionApp16
{
    public class Function2
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function2> _logger;

        public Function2(ILogger<Function2> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function2))]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("%StorageContainer:SourceImages%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message}");
        }
    }
}

FunctionApp16.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "StorageContainer:SourceImages": "test"
  }
}

OUTPUT:


For some reason this isn't working for me still. I will accept this as the answer though because it seems like it should be working, and this should be how to do it. I have a similar but different question that I asked that I will link here in case I find the solution I will update both. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78306419/isolated-worker-azure-function-function-input-bindings-error-on-startup

This only works with local.settings.json. If you need to use a separate setting file, the process to add the settings in Progam.cs is broken.

What SERGIOL has said is the only sensible thing I've seen about this problem to date.  For everyone testing, stop testing locally, deploy to Azure, it does not work on Azure, works fine locally.
To Summarize, obtaining binding attributes like QueueTrigger or BlobTrigger just do NOT work supplying a connection string from appsettings.json.  How does the functions team not know this?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem, make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers, the relevant advantage which your solution achieves. Consider taking the [tour].

I’ve just upgraded my InProcess .Net 6 Function app to Isolated .Net 8. I’m facing the same issue. I was previously declaring object like configuration in local.settings.json below Values property. It is correctly loaded by the configuration builder but can’t be used within trigger bindings using % MyBlock:MyParam% expressions.
The only workaround is to flatten those expressions within the Values property : MyBlock__MyParam.
I haven’t deployed yet on Azure but I guess it won’t work also as the source configuration is coming from AppConfiguration.
EDIT: I just found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78897967/323211 which works perfectly on local development. I can keep using my object blocks without flattening them.
